# Why is the master branch automatically deleted when I create a new branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-config

I'm just a beginner and I practiced merging.

1. I deleted folder A that I practiced.
2. And I created a new folder B. I did the following work at B.

```
$ git init
$ (master) touch defalt.txt
$ (master) git switch -c foo
$ (foo) git branch
>>> *foo
```

3. The master branch has disappeared.
   Maybe something is wrong when working at A.
4. My`.git/config`

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
efilemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
precomposeunicode = true
```

How can I check the problem?
Did I change the git setting?
I don't know what's wrong. Please help me

Comment: I'm not sure how git handles this internally but it doesn't seem like you are committing anything to master. In the end a branch is just a label that points to a specific commit.

Comment: Immediately after `git init`, the file `.git/HEAD` contains `ref: refs/heads/master`, but `.git/refs/heads/master` doesn't actually get created until you actually create a first commit.  When you use `git switch`, the contents of `.git/HEAD` are updated, but `refs/heads/master` never got created. So it's not so much that `master` disappeared as your prompt was incorrectly reporting `master` as existing in the first place. (This is somewhat of corner case due to the repository having just been created. Usually, `.git/HEAD` *does* refer to a branch that actually exists.)

Comment: Even after `git switch`, the branch `foo` does not really exist yet either, only as a reference in `.git/HEAD`, as with `master`.

Comment: Oh, my god! I miss the commit! Why did I forgot that! Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Your prompt is (in)directly using the contents of `.git/HEAD` as the name of the current branch, but the branch it references doesn't actually exist until you create a commit. (You can see this by looking at the contents of `.git/HEAD` and the contents of `.git/refs/heads`.)

`master` didn't disappear; it never existed in the first place.

`.git/HEAD` might refer to a branch head (which may or may not exist/refer to a commit yet) or it might refer to some other commit that is *not* a branch head (a so-called detached head). (There might also be some other corner case I've missed.)

Comment: to be fair: most git prompts use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref` to get the current branch name, including a yet-to-be-created one, so I would mention this as a "works as expected" rather than an "incorrect handling".

Comment: That's fair. I'll reword the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `master` is what is known as an *unborn branch* — a branch that exists *potentially* in a new repository, just so your first commit has a branch to go onto, but *does not exist in reality* until and unless you *do* put a commit onto it.

An unborn branch is *never* listed in `git branch`; the `git switch` in your question is a red herring, as the branch wasn't listed *before* the switch either! It won't be listed unless you switch back to it and commit onto it.

Comment: As @chepner has rightly pointed out, the reason you're confused is mostly that you've configured your prompt to state the name of the "current" branch. If you hadn't done that, you would never have known about the unborn branch. (I'm not saying that's a bad way to configure your prompt; on the contrary.)